# system of equations solving with only that information

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Hi would would I go around to solve the following, there is no other information stat is given other than the fact that i have already expanded this from this

$(25-y)(x+8)=523$

$25x-8y=323$

Comment: Have you tried expanding the left side of the first equation?

Comment: Note that since $(25-y)(x+8)=200+25x-8y-xy$ we get $xy=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You can rewrite the second equation as $y=\frac 18(25x-323)$, substitute that into the first and you will have a quadratic equation.  It will give you two values for $x$, which you can plug into the second to find $y$.